# Can deterministic and stochastic models be used to models different parts of the same phenomenon?

Tags: theoretical-biology

A biological phenomenon including two different causally dependent phenomenon occurs in the cell. (Phenomenon2 initiates as a result of phenomenon1). Phenomenon1 and phenomenon2 are linked with feedback loops.

The entire phenomenon is wished to be mathematically modeled. Phenomenon2 is already modeled with a deterministic model including 3 PDEs. Since phenomenon1 and phenomenon2 are linked with feedback loops, they will be connected to mathematically model the phenomenon in its entirety.

Can phenomenon1 be modeled with a stochastic model? If not please explain why.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I think that the question requires more clarity, sinc eteh answer depends on which stochastic and deterministic models one talks about. The first thing that comes to mind is that deterministic models are often just the averages of stochastic equations.

Comment: I would suggest that the physics StackExchange community (https://physics.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to get a good answer to this question. It seems that you are interested in the problem of modeling generally rather than a specific biological application, and they have more expertise in that domain.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not appear to be about biology as defined in the [help]. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and [ask] a good question.

Comment: @RogerVadim I see, thanks.

Comment: @MaximilianPress I think you are right, but sometimes different fields might have different perspectives/tools for the same method or for their analysis. I was curious about the approach of an expert in biological modelling on this question. If there was a biological modelling SE I would put it there. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: @tyersome I can also delete it, if you prefer. Thanks.

Comment: If you also can't see any way to make your question fit here, then yes I think it would be best to delete it. Thanks!